# Variadic Count function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I would like to write a generic function, which count occurrences of specified values in a container.

I want the call to look like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int GetI() { return i; }
    int i = 0;
};

Count(f, [](auto& f) { return f.GetI(); }, // from container 'f' with provided getter
            0, i0,    // count 0s into variable i0
            37, i37); // count 37s into variable i37
```

I have written version for 2 values and now I'm not sure, how to make it variadic (especially the if elseif ).

```
template <typename Container, typename ValueGetter, typename SizeType, typename T1, typename T2>
void Count(Container& c, ValueGetter valueGetter, T1&& t1, SizeType& out1, T2&& t2, SizeType& out2)
{
    using GetVal = decltype(valueGetter(c[0]));
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>, GetVal>::value, "Types don't match!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<T2>, GetVal>::value, "Types don't match!");

    for (auto& elm : c)
    {
        const auto& val = valueGetter(elm);
        if (val == t1) ++out1;
        else if (val == t2) ++out2;
    }
}
```

How to make it variadic?

[Here](http://ideone.com/AkddbC) is the small code on ideone to play with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a helper template function to unwind the variadic parameter pack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename value_type>
void Count_all(value_type &&value)
{
}

template<typename value_type, typename first_value, typename first_counter,
     typename ...Args>
void Count_all(value_type &&value, first_value &&value1,
           first_counter &&counter1,
           Args && ...args)
{
    if (value == value1)
        ++counter1;

    Count_all(value, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}


template<typename Container, typename ValueGetter, typename ...Args>
void Count(const Container &c,
       ValueGetter &&getter,
       Args && ...args)
{
    for (const auto &v:c)
        Count_all(getter(v), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> i{1,2,3,3,5,9,8};

    int n_3=0;
    int n_8=0;

    Count(i, [](const int &i) { return i; },
          3, n_3,
          8, n_8);

    std::cout << n_3 << ' ' << n_8 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking a bunch of bare variadic arguments, you could accept pairs or tuples of arguments and unpack them yourself:

```
template <typename Container, typename ValueGetter, typename... Pairs>
void Count(Container& c, ValueGetter valueGetter, Pairs&&... pairs)
{
    for (auto& elm : c)
    {
        auto check_value = [&](auto&& pair){
            const auto& val = valueGetter(elm);
            if (val == std::get<0>(pair)) ++std::get<1>(pair);
        };

        //Horrible hack to get around the lack of fold expressions
        (void)std::initializer_list<int> {
            (check_value(pairs), 0)...
        };
    }   
}
```

You can then add in any `static_assert`s you want to give better compiler errors on misuse. You can use this like so:

```
Count(f, [](auto& f) { return f.GetI(); }, 
      std::forward_as_tuple(0, i0),
      std::forward_as_tuple(37, i37));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74dca483f95e7b57)